# Writing data to .cof file

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, coff, code-composer

I'm very new to coding and have been utterly baffled (for the second time today) by something google can't fix. I am writing code using Code Composer 4 on Windows. My code has no errors but the fopen("coffic.cof", "w") just doesn't change the data within the file at all (and doesn't create the file if the file is deleted) and I can't see why. Any ideas?

```
#include "dsk6713_aic23.h"      //codec-DSK support file
Uint32 fs=DSK6713_AIC23_FREQ_8KHZ;  //set sampling rate
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h> 
#define pi 3.1415927
#include "coffic.cof"

void main()
{
    double hpf, fs, fco, atn, fat, tp, k, ad, m, n, o, da, db, dc;
    FILE *fp;
    int c, d, e, f, g, h, i, q, r, s, t, u, v;
    hpf = 0;            //for a high-pass filter input 1, for a low-pass filter input 0
    fs = 8000;          //input samping frequency here
    fco = 2400;         //input cut-off frequency here
    atn = 17;           //input attenuation (dB) here
    fat = 3500;         //input the frequency of attenuation here
    tp = 1/fs;
    k = tan(pi*fco*tp);
    ad = tan(pi*fat*tp);
    m = (log10((pow(10,(atn/10)))-1))/(2*(log10(ad/k)));
    o = abs(m);
    n = ceil(o);

    da = 1.414;
    c = (pow(2,15)*k*k/(1+da*k+k*k));
    d = (pow(2,15)*2*k*k/(1+da*k+k*k));
    e = (pow(2,15)*k*k/(1+da*k+k*k));
    q = (pow(2,15)*(2-2*k*k)/(1+da*k+k*k));
    r = (pow(2,15)*(-1+k-k*k)/(1+da*k+k*k));

    fp = fopen("U:\DSK6713\Ivo\CSP\coffic.cof", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error. Unable to open coffic.cof");
        exit(0);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "int a[3]={%d, d%, %d};\n", c, d, e);
    fprintf(fp, "int b[3]={1, d%, %d};\n", q ,r);
    fprintf(fp, "int x[3]={0,0,0};\nint y[3]={0,0,0};\n");

    fflush(fp);

    fclose(fp);

    comm_intr();                   //init DSK, codec, McBSP
    while(1);                      //infinite loop
}

interrupt void c_int11()         //interrupt service routine 
{
    short input;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("U:\DSK6713\Ivo\CSP\coffic.cof", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error. Unable to open coffic.cof");
        exit(0);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];

    input=input_sample();
    x[0]=input;

    y[0]=a[0]*x[0]+a[1]*x[1]+a[2]*x[2]+b[1]*y[1]+b[2]*x[2];     

    y[0]=y[0]>>15;                      
    input=(short)y[0];
    output_sample(input);   //output data  
    return;
}
```

Comment: `fp = fopen("U:\DSK6713\Ivo\CSP\coffic.cof", "w");` The backslash marks an escape sequence. None of `\D`, `\I`, `\C` and `\c` is an escape sequence I've ever heard of. Doesn't the compiler barf on that? (Should be "U:\\DSK6713\\Ivo\\CSP\\coffic.cof".)

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = fopen("U:\DSK6713\Ivo\CSP\coffic.cof", "w");
```

Does not create a file it assumes that you already have a file called coffic.cof on your computer. I usually have trouble with using the write function of fopen so I usually use the append function.
Try this

```
fp = fopen("U:\DSK6713\Ivo\CSP\coffic.cof", "a");
```

I am new to programming too but this has worked for me when "w" has not.